# Upload file with drag & drop using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have developed a Python program using Selenium to upload files through drag and drop. In the actual scenario, the user drags the file from their system, and after dropping it onto the site's page, an element with the structure "//div[contains(@class, 'drops-container')]" appears after a short delay. The user then needs to release the file inside this element for the upload to take place.

I am trying to replicate this process using Selenium in Python, please help me

Answer (score 5):

You can use *ActionChains()* from the Selenium library to achieve this.

Here's an example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Initializing the browser and the website 
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("/website/where/you/want/to/perform/drag-and-drop")

# Find the file input element to interact with
file_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")  # Replace with your file input locator

# Replace 'file_path' with the actual path of the file you want to upload
file_path = '/path/to/your/file.txt'

# Perform the drag-and-drop operation
action_chains = ActionChains(browser)
action_chains.drag_and_drop(file_input, browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'drops-container')]")).perform()

# Input the file path into the file input (if required by the website)
file_input.send_keys(file_path)

# To be on the safer side, wait for the upload to complete then move ahead
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium's ActionChains class allows you to automate complex actions like drag and drop.

example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Set the path to your webdriver
driver_path = "PATH_TO_YOUR_WEBDRIVER"

# Replace with the path of the file you want to upload
file_path = "C:\\path\\to\\your\\file.txt"

# URL of the page where the upload will happen
url = "YOUR_TARGET_URL"

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the file input element to be visible and interactable
# Replace with the correct selector
file_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']"))
)

# Set the file path in the input element
file_input.send_keys(file_path)

# Use ActionChains to handle drag and drop
action = ActionChains(driver)

# Start the drag action
action.click_and_hold(file_input)

# Move to the target drop area
# Replace with the correct selector
drop_area = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'drops-container')]"))
)
action.move_to_element(drop_area)

# Perform the drop action
action.release().perform()

# Optionally, wait for the upload to complete or for any response on the page
# WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT).until(CONDITION)

# Close the driver
driver.quit()
```